# Kotlin Deserialize variables from abstract class

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin

I have an object that extends an abstract class that inherits an interface. When using kotlin serialization, it will not serialize the properties on the abstract class.
For example:

```
@Serializable
class User(private val uid: String): BaseClass()

abstract class BaseClass(): CacheClass {
    override val cacheDate: Long = 0L
}

interface CacheClass {
    val cacheDate: Long
}
```

The variable `cacheDate` will never get serialized. How can I ensure that the variables defined on the abstract class will in fact be serialized?
I am not looking for other libraries to use. I am using Kotlin Serialization found [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

Comment: Can you provide a runnable piece of code that we can use to reproduce your problem and try to fix it? I've tried to copy-and-paste the code you showed but the project requires external dependencies and setup you already have...

Comment: @PietroMartinelli You need to have kotlin serialization plugin and then simply try to serialize the user class. I cannot provide a full intellij build.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/examples.md:

> Supported properties:
>
> - Class constructor val and var properties. It is required for constructor to have only properties (no parameters).
> - In case of usage of internal serialization (@Serializable annotation on class), both body vals and vars are supported with any visibility levels.

But `cacheDate` is neither; it's a body property of the superclass without `@Serializable`. You can try annotating the superclass, but I would expect it not to work, based on the description in [the proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/serialization/proposals/extensions/serialization.md); if it doesn't, [write a custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md).